# How to filter results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query which is used to obtain information about the owner of a vehicle at a particular point in time, when it is sighted (from the `vehicle_sightings` table). I have attached a snippet of part of the query below:

```
SELECT 
    sighting_id
FROM
    vehicle_sightings
        INNER JOIN
    vehicle_vrn ON vehicle_sightings.plate = vehicle_vrn.vrnno
        INNER JOIN
    vehicle_ownership ON vehicle_vrn.fk_sysno = vehicle_ownership.fk_sysno
WHERE
    vehicle_sightings.seenDate >= vehicle_ownership.ownership_start_date
        AND (vehicle_sightings.seenDate <= vehicle_ownership.ownership_end_date
        OR vehicle_ownership.ownership_end_date IS NULL
        OR vehicle_ownership.ownership_end_date = '0001-01-01 00:00:00')
```

This works well for most scenarios where a vehicle only has one owner in its history.  However, there are some instances where the `ownership_end_date` field is not filled in (it **is** filled in for most cases, as it indicates that a vehicle would have changed hands, and is from that stage onwards passed on to a new owner).  In these instances where it is not filled in (or left default), all entries for that ownership history are returned, such as the below case:

[image]

In that case above, the query returns both of those records as the `seenDate` fits in both of them since the end date is not filled in (and has the default value in that case).  I therefore need to modify my query to return the record with the highest `ownership_start_date` in those cases.

I tried to do this by adding the following at the end:

`GROUP BY sighting_id HAVING seenDate >= MAX(ownership_start_date)`

This however did not work, as many less records were returned. Is there a clean way this can be achieved, maybe without the GROUP BY?

Comment: You can do it with a self-exclusion join. I wrote about those joins here: http://adam-bernier.appspot.com/post/38001/the-self-exclusion-join

Comment: It is not really clear what you want your output to be.  Can you edit your question and clearly state the desired result?

Comment: In some other RDBMSs this is easier to do with windowing functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, using a default date as you have is an extremely bad idea. You should already have an idea of that, because now you're stuck coding against a hard-coded date in some scenarios. When another developer is coding against the database (or even you at a later date) they now have to both know and remember that they have to code for exceptions based on some hard-coded date.

Further, your `ownership_end_date` should always be after the `ownership_start_date`, which this "default" date is now going to violate. If you don't know the date or the date doesn't exist yet then it should be `NULL` - that's exactly what `NULL` is for - unknown.

For your specific issue, you can do this with a `LEFT JOIN` that checks for other owners that fit the criteria and excludes the row if a better one exists. You didn't provide all of your table structures and it was a little unclear on whether or not you just wanted the latest owner before the sighted date (what I've done) or all owners who owned the car after the sighted date, so I don't know if this works, but something like this:

```
SELECT 
    VS.sighting_id    -- ALWAYS use table aliases or prefixes for clarity
FROM
    vehicle_sightings VS
INNER JOIN vehicle_vrn VRN ON VRN.vrnno = VS.plate
INNER JOIN vehicle_ownership VO ON VO.fk_sysno = VRN.fk_sysno
LEFT OUTER JOIN vehicle_ownership VO2 ON
    VO2.fk_sysno = VRN.fk_sysno AND
    VO2.ownership_start_date <= VS.seenDate AND
    (
        VO2.ownership_end_date >= VS.seenDate OR
        VO2.ownership_end_date IS NULL OR
        VO2.ownership_end_date = '0001-01-01 00:00:00'
    ) AND
    VO2.ownership_start_date > VO.ownership_start_date
WHERE
    VS.seenDate >= VO.ownership_start_date AND
    (
        VS.seenDate <= VO.ownership_end_date OR
        VO.ownership_end_date IS NULL OR
        VO.ownership_end_date = '0001-01-01 00:00:00'
    ) AND
    VO2.id IS NULL    -- Or some other non-nullable column
```

One last caveat: decide on a naming convention and stick to it (`seenDate` vs `ownership_end_date` for example) and use names that make sense (what is an `fk_sysno`??)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me get on the right track. Unfortunately the database structure is not for me to decide, so I need to work with it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which doesn't require a subquery. It ensures that there exists no ownership records greater than the record which is returned.

```
SELECT 
    sighting_id
FROM
    vehicle_sightings
        INNER JOIN
    vehicle_vrn ON vehicle_sightings.plate = vehicle_vrn.vrnno
        INNER JOIN
    vehicle_ownership ON vehicle_vrn.fk_sysno = vehicle_ownership.fk_sysno
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    vehicle_ownership vo2 ON vo2.fk_sysno = vehicle_ownership.fk_sysno
        AND vo2.ownership_start_date > vehicle_ownership.ownership_start_date
WHERE
    vehicle_sightings.seenDate >= vehicle_ownership.ownership_start_date
        AND (vehicle_sightings.seenDate <= vehicle_ownership.ownership_end_date
        OR vehicle_ownership.ownership_end_date IS NULL
        OR vehicle_ownership.ownership_end_date = '0001-01-01 00:00:00')
        AND vo2.fk_sysno IS NULL
```